# How do you install an SSL certificate on an AWS EC2 Wordpress server?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

How can I install an SSL certificate to my EC2 instance running wordpress? I have tried the following links:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-certificate-manager-deploy-ssltls-based-apps-on-aws/
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html
However I have been unable to successfully have any changes propagate.
Steps I followed:
-Request ACM SSL Certificate
-Create a Load Balancer with the SSL Certificate attached
-Attach load balancer to EC2 instance

Comment: Are you using a load balancer? Are you using Apache or Nginx?

Comment: @MarkB I'm using Apache. and I did set up a load balancer.

Comment: If you are using a load balancer, then create an SSL certificate in the AWS Certificate Manager service, and add it to the load balancer. Search for that and you will find plenty of questions and answers about doing exactly that on this site.

Comment: Links I've tried to follow and failed:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-deregister-register-instances.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html
https://community.bitnami.com/t/setup-ssl-with-aws-and-loadbalancer/52296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned you cannot use AWS's certificate. But you can use another excellent free certificate provider - [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

They provide an easy to install and use tool that supports Apache and Nginx - along with most flavors of Linux.

Comment: I am going to second John Veldboom's answer. Let's Encrypt is very easy to  use. We have not found any problems with their certificates. Installation is easy and they support auto-renewal. Note: for most setups I recommend using ALB or NLB and offloading SSL onto the load balancer using Amazon SSL certificates, but in some situations, this is overkill. When we setup load balancers in front of EC2 instances in private subnets we also install Lets Encrypt so that we can use SSL from our corporate network to the EC2 instances via the Bastion Host (OpenVPN).

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER:
I was able to use Let's Encrypt through the AWS CLI to add an auto renewing SSL certificate. The link below was very helpful despite being on Google Cloud. The instructions transfer over since both servers use bitnami for the Wordpress.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBnQkH1v-Xw&app=desktop
I only had to make one change to the instructions and that was to change the RewriteRule to be 
    RewriteRule https://(domain here) [R,L]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go is to manually set it up by logging in to your server. You should get some cheap SSL certificate and have it installed inside your `/etc/apache2/ssl` folder. Make sure your 443 port is opened and that `openssl` is installed on your server and enabled.

Here is a complete guide on how to do what I just said https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-add-ssl-certificate-to-laravel-on-ec2-aws-18104cc036d1

Answer (score 0):

You can attach this certificate on load balancer and forward this to backend instance port 80
443->80
When applying certificate to elb you have two option to upload certificate into ACM or to IAM you can choose anyone and simply copy paste the certificate derails

Comment: Hi @rahul-sharma can you answer more for this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952853/while-using-aws-free-ssl-i-am-getting-session-issue-on-ec2